# Heroku failing to start my node app because its trying to do it with nodemon

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodemon

I'm deploying my node app to Heroku and it's trying to invoke it with nodemon rather than the `node app.js` I have defined. My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: npm start
```

And when I push to heroku the dyno crashes with this error:

```
2014-03-24T19:24:59.669412+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.1 start /app
2014-03-24T19:24:59.669412+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon app.js
2014-03-24T19:24:59.669412+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-03-24T19:24:59.669412+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-03-24T19:24:59.710228+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-03-24T19:24:59.701246+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: nodemon: not found
```

I even tried npm installing nodemon as a package.json dependency, and checking in node_modules/nodemon but no luck. (nodemon needs to be installed with `npm install nodemon -g` for that to work anyway)

Any ideas?

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "requirejs": "~2.1.10",
        "underscore": "~1.5.2",
        "express": "~3.4.8",
        "ejs": "~0.8.5",
        "less-middleware": "~0.1.15",
        "socket.io": "~0.9.16",
        "tail": "~0.3.5",
        "async": "~0.2.10",
        "mongoose": "~3.8.5",
        "mkdirp": "~0.3.5",
        "ejs-locals": "~1.0.2",
        "aws-sdk": "~2.0.0-rc8",
        "knox": "~0.8.8",
        "connect-multiparty": "~1.0.3",
        "uuid": "~1.4.1",
        "nodemon": "~1.0.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.2",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-recess": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.9.0",
        "grunt-forever": "~0.4.1",
        "matchdep": "~0.3.0",
        "jshint": "~2.4.3",
        "precommit-hook": "~0.3.10",
        "mocha": "~1.17.1",
        "supertest": "~0.9.0",
        "chai": "~1.9.0",
        "sinon": "~1.8.2",
        "karma-sinon": "~1.0.2",
        "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
        "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
        "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
        "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.3",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.2",
        "karma": "~0.10.9",
        "karma-mocha": "~0.1.1",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
        "karma-chai": "~0.1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "precommit": {
            "lint": true
        }
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x"
    }
}
```

**Update**

Sorry to have left everyone hanging all this time! If I remember correctly my issue in the end was my buildpack which was overriding the web: role in my Procfile.

I've since switched to different buildpacks, namely:
ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

With the following .buildpacks file:

```
ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack
heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

And my Procfile looks like this:

```
web: bin/start-nginx ./node_modules/.bin/forever --minUptime 10000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your `Procfile` to this:

```
web: node app.js
```

Being `app.js` the entry point to your app.

This is assuming you don't really need `nodemon` in your app, since you have listed it at the `package.json` sample you provided.

Comment: Done, with no luck. I've removed scripts and nodemon dep from the package.json, and my Procfile is this: ```web: node app.js``` What's also telling is when I heroku ps i get this:

```=== web (1X): `npm start`
web.1: crashed 2014/03/24 16:18:05 (~ 1m ago)```

I don't have npm start or nodemon mentioned anywhere. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Hang on I've figured out what I was doing wrong all along and it had nothing to do with heroku. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Sorry about that @ndelvalle I did edit the original question with details about the problem and the solution.

Comment: @diosney i have the same issue, how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I'm working on deployed my node js appication in heroku by using nodemon, for it's working fine.
we have to follow few step to reslove nodemon is not found.

1)Package.json

```
 npm start: nodemon server.js
```

2)We need to modified procfile like below.

```
 web: nodemon server.js
```

3)Use below command line to login for heroku

```
 $ heroku login
```

4)Create new application

```
   $heroku create <appication-name>
```

I think most of the developer directly deployed to heroku through github Id. Locally node_modules are work fine ,after deployed your application in heroku (inside we are n't able to access the node_modules), so for that we have access the respository.

5)Clone the repository from heroku

```
$ heroku git:clone -a <application-name>
$ cd cv-application
```

Now we are able access the application.

6)Delete you node_modules and try to install package by using below command.

```
$ npm install.
```

Deploy your changes.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master.
```

npm version sholud be 6.4.1.

Comment: This will not work as nodemon needs to be installed globally, not locally. In Package.json you have the local packages only

Answer (score 1):

I know that OP got the answer but I thought I might share what worked for me, in a slightly different senario:

Procfile contains the following:

```
web: npm start
```

And for my package.json file I defined:

```
"scripts":{
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

And that fixed this issue for me.

Comment: does this automatically restart app if it crashes, it sure doesn't look like it

Answer (score 0):

Include nodemon as dev dependencies not as dependencies.

using this command remove nodemon.

```
npm uninstall nodemon
```

now install nodemon

```
npm install -D nodemon
```

In production or in deployment you shouldn't be using nodemon.